# C++: Fast structure with two related keys

Tags: c++, search, optimization, iteration, stdmap

I have a situation where I have a container which needs to hold an ID (IDs are unique) and a data value. I also need to keep these IDs in an order. The tuple of these variables will be looked up by the ID, but then processed in order up to the found element, ie I don't always want to process the whole container. For this, I've got a simple solution of

```
// ordinal, { ID, data }
std::map<int64, pair<int64, data_t> >
```

Which I will first search for ID by iterating through and comparing a search value with the first field of the pair, giving me an iterator to walk up to, then I will process all elements up to this position. Is there a better way of doing this (by my count this is O(2n))?

Comment: you can use std::map instead of std::pair which then give you faster search but will waste your memory.

Comment: Are both of the `int64` you show here the ID? Lookup in a `map` is O(log n), not O(n).

Comment: The first is the ordinal, the second (in the pair) is the ID. Under that scheme I am not doing lookups, just iterating through twice. I am being passed the ID, from this I need to find the ordinal the process the elements in order up to and including this ordinal

Comment: Any reason not to process the elements of the `map` while you're doing the search? And why a `map` instead of a `vector`, will you be inserting ordinals out of order?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Boost.Bimap if you want to index on values as well as keys. That way you can look up a pair in the map based on it's value. Without this or similar, this will have to be done by brute force (=> iterate over the map by hand).

Otherwise you could use [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) to help you find the pair with the ID you're looking for but it will be the same speed as iterating over the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap `ordinal` and `ID` and store them in a map of maps:

```
//                 ID              ordinal data
std::unordered_map<int64, std::map<int64, data_t>> container;
```

This will allow you to find an element with `ID` given and minimum possible `ordinal` in `O(log N)` time:

```
container[ID].begin(); // Has ID given, smallest possible ordinal and corresponding data
                       // Equal to container[ID].end() if not found
```

After that, you can compare the `ordinal` of the object found to the threshold given.

**UP:** Of course, if your `ID`s are unique, there's no need in the nested `map`: you can just use `std::unordered_map<int64, std::pair<int64, data_t>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the ordinal is strictly for maintaining the order and there won't be any gaps, I'd do something simple like this:

```
    int64_t givenID = whereToQuit;

    std::vector< int64_t >                ordinal_to_ID; 
    std::unordered_map< int64_t, data_t > data_map;

    using datapair_t = std::pair< int64_t, data_t >;
    void do_whatever( datapair_t );

    bool done = false;
    do 
    {
        int64_t ID = ordinal_to_ID[ i ];
        do_whatever( datapair_t( ID, data_map[ ID ]) ); 
        done = ID == givenID;
    }
    while ( !done );
```